# Javascript: Is it safe to refer to the <html> DOM-node?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Working in an environment where only css-selectors are available for retrieving elements I want to obtain the element in the DOM which covers the whole browser-window. Using developer tools I found out that `<body>` has some margin in my case which makes it unsuitable for my requirements.

I further discovered that the `<html>` element covers the whole area of the browser-window. Is it safe to use that DOM-node when it is about the document properties? I.e. getting the width/height for example?

Does by any chance `<html>` correspond to what is referred to as `document` in javascript?

EDIT: Side note on the setup:

I'm working with interns wrapped WD version and want to coordinate mouse movements relative to the document. I was aiming for using a method like `selectByCssSelector` to coodinate mouse movements with respect to that selected element. Working with the `<html>` node here seems to work out so far. I just never touched the `<html>` node before and never saw anyone else do, that is why I wanted to be assured that it is not bad using that node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document object is a DOM HTML object so, yes, it does correspond to the `<html>` tag, but not in the way you think. It is not like a `<body>` or `<span>` tag. It tells the browser that the following code or information is HTML. Just like how `<?php` tells the server that there is PHP code and `<script type="text/javascript">` tells the browser that there is Javascript code. For more information on that, check out [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/) page.

If you don't want to get the width and height of the body, you can use `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`. This should get the height and width of the entire window (excluding any scrollbars or toolboxes).

You can also use documentElement to get the width and height of the entire document.

```
var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
```

This may be the final answer that you are looking for, but you can also find the width and height of the entire document by using `document` in jQuery.

```
var width = $(document).width();
var height = $(document).height();
```

Comment: I can't select 'window' with css selectors though - can I?

Comment: @user2820379 There is no CSS selector for a window because there is just one window (the page you are on).  Give me an example of some code and I can try to show you how to apply it.

Comment: I recommend you to take a look at **[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/)** to understand a little more the way of this works

Comment: @kmsdev - w3schools is one of the worst resources.

Comment: The corresponding element to `<html>` is `document.documentElement`. In other words, `document.querySelector("html") === document.documentElement; // true`

Comment: @user2820379 - load an empty html page and write the following line in it console.log($(this)); or console.log(this); without jquery, and take a look at the output so you can understand it better.

Comment: @cookiemonster Added an example of that.

Comment: Updated my question with regards to the setup.

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan I respect your opinion but _I don't think so_. I tried to comment something constructive. Anyway this is not the place to this discussion.

Comment: @user2820379 Using the HTML node should be fine. Just be sure that you aren't including anything that you don't want to be including. There are certain things within `<html>` and not `<body>` that you may not want to count in your width and height. It seems like, for your case, you do want to count everything.

Answer (score 1):

The `html` represents all markup and content in the document, but it does not correspond to the `document` object. Instead, it appears as its property, `document.documentElement` (though it can be referred to in many other ways, too, e.g. `document.children[0]`).

As you note, the `body` element may have a margin, and by default it has a 8px margin on all sides. Thus, instead of it, the `html` element is the one you should refer to as corresponding to the entire viewport in the browser window, assuming that you let the dimensions of the `html` element default to that. You can get the dimensions as `document.documentElement.clientWidth` and `document.documentElement.clientHeight`.

However, for historical reasons, by CSS definitions, the [background of the `html` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#background) always covers the entire canvas even if the element has been set to smaller dimensions. You can see this if you set both a background and a border on it; the background may extend outside the border. Moreover, the CSS spec also specifies that if no background set for `html`, the background of `body` is used instead.